# How/where do I use PIVOT?

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table of data that shows multiple rows for a single piece of data.  In the example below, I have a column called, "Location Type" that shows, "BH" and "TPI".  BH and TPI each have a specific location shown in the "Location" column.  Instead of having a new row for BH and TPI, I'd like two new columns that show the location data for that row.  I included a couple of rows of data below.  I suspect I need to use PIVOT here but I've been having a hard time figuring out where the PIVOT needs to come in.  Could anybody provide some guidance or show me a solution?

Here's a sample of the data from the query.

| API14 | First Prod Date | Location Type | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43013540070000 | 2/8/2021 | BH | Township 3S Range 4W Section 17 DUCHESNE County |
| 43013540070000 | 2/8/2021 | TPI | Township 3S Range 4W Section 18 DUCHESNE County |

Here's the format I would like to see:

| API14 | First Prod Date | BH Location | TPI Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43013540070000 | 2/8/2021 | Township 3S Range 4W Section 17 DUCHESNE County | Township 3S Range 4W Section 18 DUCHESNE County |

Here's my code so far:

```
DECLARE @SearchYear AS VARCHAR(4) = '2021'
DECLARE @SearchMonth AS VARCHAR(2) = '6'

SELECT
    dbo.BuildAPI14(Well.WellID, Construct.SideTrack, Construct.Completion) AS 'API14',
    CAST(ConstructDate.EventDate AS DATE) AS 'First Prod Date',
    Loc.LocType AS 'Location Type',
    CONCAT('Township ',LocExt.Township,LocExt.TownshipDir,' ','Range ',LocExt.Range,LocExt.RangeDir,' Section ',LocExt.Sec,' ',RefCounty.CountyName,' County') AS 'Location',
    tblAPDTracker.SpacingRule AS 'Spacing Rule',
    Lease.Number AS 'Entity Number',
    WellHistory.WHComments AS 'Well History Comments'
FROM Well
    LEFT JOIN Construct ON Construct.WellKey = Well.PKey
    LEFT JOIN ConstructReservoir ON ConstructReservoir.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey
    LEFT JOIN Lease ON Lease.Pkey = ConstructReservoir.LeaseKey
    LEFT JOIN WellHistory ON WellHistory.WellKey = Construct.WellKey
    LEFT JOIN tblAPDTracker ON LEFT(tblAPDTracker.APINO,10) = Well.WellID
    LEFT JOIN Loc ON loc.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey AND Loc.LocType IN ('BH','TPI')
    LEFT JOIN LocExt ON LocExt.LocKey = Loc.PKey
    LEFT JOIN ConstructDate ON ConstructDate.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey AND ConstructDate.Event = 'FirstProduction'
    LEFT JOIN RefCounty ON RefCounty.PKey = LocExt.County
WHERE
    WorkType = 'ENTITY' AND
    WellHistory.ModifyUser = 'UTAH\rachelmedina' AND
    YEAR(WellHistory.ModifyDate) = @SearchYear AND
    MONTH(WellHistory.ModifyDate) = @SearchMonth
GROUP BY
    Well.WellID,
    Construct.SideTrack,
    Construct.Completion,
    ConstructDate.EventDate,
    Loc.LocType,
    LocExt.Township,
    LocExt.TownshipDir,
    LocExt.Range,
    LocExt.RangeDir,
    LocExt.Sec,
    RefCounty.CountyName,
    tblAPDTracker.SpacingRule,
    Lease.Number,
    WellHistory.WHComments,
    WellHistory.ModifyDate
ORDER BY
    Well.WellId,
    WellHistory.ModifyDate DESC
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you_ [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh I'm trying to add the data from my example in a table so anybody can grab it.  It looks good in my edit but once I hit save it turns into a garbled mess.  I'll keep trying and see if I can simplify things more.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't even read that tiny image text...)

Comment: @jarlh I'll add some sample data as well as the results that I'd like to see.

Comment: @jarlh Is there anything I could do to this post to get more reponses?  I added some sample data and the expected results.  I also shortened my query to be specific to the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select *
from
(
SELECT
    dbo.BuildAPI14(Well.WellID, Construct.SideTrack, Construct.Completion) AS 'API14',
    CAST(ConstructDate.EventDate AS DATE) AS 'First Prod Date',
    Loc.LocType AS 'Location Type',
    CONCAT('Township ',LocExt.Township,LocExt.TownshipDir,' ','Range ',LocExt.Range,LocExt.RangeDir,' Section ',LocExt.Sec,' ',RefCounty.CountyName,' County') AS 'Location' --,
--    tblAPDTracker.SpacingRule AS 'Spacing Rule',
--    Lease.Number AS 'Entity Number',
--    WellHistory.WHComments AS 'Well History Comments'
FROM Well
    LEFT JOIN Construct ON Construct.WellKey = Well.PKey
    LEFT JOIN ConstructReservoir ON ConstructReservoir.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey
    LEFT JOIN Lease ON Lease.Pkey = ConstructReservoir.LeaseKey
    LEFT JOIN WellHistory ON WellHistory.WellKey = Construct.WellKey
    LEFT JOIN tblAPDTracker ON LEFT(tblAPDTracker.APINO,10) = Well.WellID
    LEFT JOIN Loc ON loc.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey AND Loc.LocType IN ('BH','TPI')
    LEFT JOIN LocExt ON LocExt.LocKey = Loc.PKey
    LEFT JOIN ConstructDate ON ConstructDate.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey AND ConstructDate.Event = 'FirstProduction'
    LEFT JOIN RefCounty ON RefCounty.PKey = LocExt.County
WHERE
    WorkType = 'ENTITY' AND
    WellHistory.ModifyUser = 'UTAH\rachelmedina' AND
    YEAR(WellHistory.ModifyDate) = @SearchYear AND
    MONTH(WellHistory.ModifyDate) = @SearchMonth
GROUP BY
    Well.WellID,
    Construct.SideTrack,
    Construct.Completion,
    ConstructDate.EventDate,
    Loc.LocType,
    LocExt.Township,
    LocExt.TownshipDir,
    LocExt.Range,
    LocExt.RangeDir,
    LocExt.Sec,
    RefCounty.CountyName,
    tblAPDTracker.SpacingRule,
    Lease.Number,
    WellHistory.WHComments,
    WellHistory.ModifyDate
    ) p
pivot (min(p.Location) for [Location Type] in ([TPI], [BH])) pvt
```

The values in the pivoted column need an aggregation operator (sum, avg, min, max etc) so pick one like min or max which won't try to do anything with a string, but which will do something if you have multiple occurrences in the pivoting column (Location here).

I've also commented out the columns selected which don't appear in your sample results, which may affect what needs to appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative from pivot is to just re-join the tables using different aliases to differentiate from the "BH" vs "TPI" instances.  I also simplified the longer table names with short aliases "w" for Well, "wh" for wellhouse, etc.

Also, by seeing the hierarchy on how A -> B -> C -> D tables helps identify where the related components are. Then I copied those out for the location downward.

I removed the location type as a column and group by since the query joins simultaneously to the BH and TPI respectively.

```
DECLARE @SearchYear AS VARCHAR(4) = '2021'
DECLARE @SearchMonth AS VARCHAR(2) = '6'

SELECT
        dbo.BuildAPI14(w.WellID, c.SideTrack, c.Completion) API14,
        CAST(cd.EventDate AS DATE) 'First Prod Date',
        CONCAT('Township ', LocExtBH.Township, LocExtBH.TownshipDir,
                ' ','Range ', LocExtBH.Range, LocExtBH.RangeDir,
                ' Section ', LocExtBH.Sec,
                ' ', rcBH.CountyName, ' County') 'BH Location',

        CONCAT('Township ', LocExtTPI.Township, LocExtTPI.TownshipDir,
                ' ','Range ', LocExtTPI.Range, LocExtTPI.RangeDir,
                ' Section ', LocExtTPI.Sec,
                ' ', rcTPI.CountyName, ' County') 'TPI Location',

        ADP.SpacingRule 'Spacing Rule',
        l.Number  'Entity Number',
        wh.WHComments 'Well History Comments'
    FROM 
        Well w
            LEFT JOIN tblAPDTracker ADP
                ON w.WellID = LEFT(trk.APINO,10)
            LEFT JOIN Construct c
                ON w.PKey = c.WellKey
                LEFT JOIN ConstructReservoir cr
                    ON c.PKey = cr.ConstructKey
                    LEFT JOIN Lease l
                        ON cr.LeaseKey = l.Pkey
                LEFT JOIN WellHistory wh
                    ON c.WellKey = wh.WellKey
                LEFT JOIN ConstructDate cd
                    ON c.PKey = cd.ConstructKey 
                    AND cd.Event = 'FirstProduction'

                LEFT JOIN Loc LocBH
                    ON c.PKey = locBH.ConstructKey 
                    AND LocBH.LocType = 'BH'
                    LEFT JOIN LocExt LocExtBH
                        ON LocBH.PKey = LocExtBH.LocKey
                        LEFT JOIN RefCounty rcBH
                            ON LocExtBH.County = rcBH.PKey 

                LEFT JOIN Loc LocTPI
                    ON c.PKey = LocTPI.ConstructKey 
                    AND LocTPI.LocType = 'TPI'
                    LEFT JOIN LocExt LocExtTPI
                        ON LocTPI.PKey = LocExtTPI.LocKey
                        LEFT JOIN RefCounty rcTPI
                            ON LocExtTPI.County = rcTPI.PKey 
    WHERE
            w.WorkType = 'ENTITY' 
        AND wh.ModifyUser = 'UTAH\rachelmedina' 
        AND YEAR(wh.ModifyDate) = @SearchYear 
        AND MONTH(wh.ModifyDate) = @SearchMonth
    GROUP BY
        w.WellID,
        c.SideTrack,
        c.Completion,
        cd.EventDate,
        LocExtBH.Township,
        LocExtBH.TownshipDir,
        LocExtBH.Range,
        LocExtBH.RangeDir,
        LocExtBH.Sec,
        rcBH.CountyName,
        ADP.SpacingRule,
        l.Number,
        wh.WHComments,
        wh.ModifyDate
    ORDER BY
        w.WellId,
        wh.ModifyDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks!  Although I didn't pick your answer as the accepted answer I still appreciate the work you put into your answer.  I picked the answer that was most closely related to my original PIVOT question.  I really appreciate the re-formatting and JOIN order though.  I'm always happy to work on my formatting and follow SQL format rules!

Comment: Tagging you for the comment above to make sure you see it.